# How do I declare the return type of a SOAP method to be a map (in its WSDL)?

Tags: soap, wsdl, xsd

I am adding a method to a SOAP service. I would like this method to be able to return a map. More specifically it is map of lists (vectors/arrays). How would I capture this in its WSDL?

Answer (score 3):

Here's and XSD type for a regular map from string to string:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MapDataType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Pair" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Key" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
          <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Is this what you want?  You'll need to use this as the type for your return value.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'map of lists'

Comment: I'd suggest that this is a fair method, considering there is no Map type in XML.